# What does Minikube status "control plane" meaning

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to learn Kubernetes from [this YouTube course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X48VuDVv0do).

One hands-on thing I am trying is to install Minikube, Docker Desktop and kubectl to see the pods and containers working in real time.

I started Minikube - specifying Docker as my VM of choice

```
minikube start --vm-driver=docker
```

As I understand the Minikube will try to run both master and worker node in the same VM.
So when I try to get its status like this:

```
minikube status
```

I expected it to give me type as "Master" like what is happening at [this point](https://youtu.be/X48VuDVv0do?t=2595) but it gives "control plane".
Even:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

gives "control plane"
[image]

What is "control plane"?
It's not mentioned in [this page](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/status/).

Comment: The word ain't "panel"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/create-cluster/cluster-intro/)

> The Control Plane is responsible for managing the cluster. The Control
> Plane coordinates all activities in your cluster, such as scheduling
> applications, maintaining applications' desired state, scaling
> applications, and rolling out new updates.
>
> Control Planes manage the cluster and the nodes that are used to host
> the running applications.
>
> When you deploy applications on Kubernetes, you tell the control plane
> to start the application containers. The control plane schedules the
> containers to run on the cluster's nodes. The nodes communicate with
> the control plane using the Kubernetes API, which the control plane
> exposes. End users can also use the Kubernetes API directly to
> interact with the cluster

.

Refer this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

The "control plane" in Kubernetes refers to the components that manage the state of the cluster, such as the API server, etcd, scheduler, and controller manager.

When you run the command `minikube status --control-plane`
Minikube will check the status of the control plane components in your local Kubernetes cluster.